# KSQLDB: How to find the alternative way using window function like lag functions in KSQLDB

Tags: sql, apache-kafka, user-defined-functions, window-functions, ksqldb

I'm new KSQLDB. I would like to find the page  time spending in real time. I usually use lag functions in sql as attached code below. But I see that KSQL DB still not support window function like as sql. As I understand, it have the lastest_by_offset function in KSQL. but I would like to order by event_time, not offset.
could any one suggest me the solution?  Or If it's necessary to write the UDF.

```
with tmp As (
SELECT customer_id
, page
, ts
, lag(event_time)over(partition by customer_id order by event_time ) pv_ts
, lag(page)over(partition by customer_id order by event_time ) pv_page
 FROM AAA WHERE event_time BETWEEN DATETIME("2023-07-05") AND DATETIME_ADD("2023-07-05", INTERVAL 1 DAY) 

)

select customer_id,page,pv_page,ts,pv_ts,datetime_diff(ts, pv_ts,SECOND) diff
from tmp
```